# Auth facade doesn't work without Sanctum api as middleware in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm creating an api through which anybody can view a page, however only admin can see all posts, while users are restricted to approved only. This is implemented via `is_verified` boolean variable where admin is given value of 1 and user the value of 0. I want to create a function like this

```
public function show(){
    if(Auth::check()){
        $showAllDetails = Events::all();
        echo $showAllDetails;   
    }else {
        $showUserDetails = Events:all()->where('is_verified',1);
        echo $showUserDetails;
    }
}
```

However `Auth:check` only works if I have sanctum api in my route

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::get('view', [ViewController::class, 'show']);
});
```

If I run this code on Hoppscotch, it only shows if the admin is logged in (User don't require login). So a user can't see any post. If I remove the `auth:sanctum` middleware, only the else part of the code runs and no auth check or any stuff can run .

I need a way to incorporate both in a single function so that I can create a single route instead of creating two routes for different persons. Any way of doing such things?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function show(){
  if(Auth::check()){
    $showAllDetails = Events::all();
    echo $showAllDetails;   
  }else {
    $showUserDetails = Events::where('is_verified',1)->get();
    echo $showUserDetails;
 }
}
```

I guess your else part is incorrect query, change your else part like above

Comment: Even if the else part is incorrect, I can't run `Auth::check()` without the sanctum middleware, which means that a guest cannot view the details.

Comment: yes that is correct, the best way i can suggest is to create a guest user and create authorization token for guest user and give that guest user a name and check if auth::user name is that guest user in your show function, every time you make an API request for that user pass that guess user token as authorization bearer token.